# What do I have to do to use Facebook authentication with ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I'm new to OAuth and ServiceStack so I've been reading through the source for ServiceStack relating to FacebookAuthProvider. It seems that adding the keys for oauth.facebook.AppId and oauth.facebook.AppSecret in  in web.config should do the trick.

I then tried to do a GET on /api/auth/facebook and got an error page from facebook. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Make sure the url for the AppId/Token in your https://developers.facebook.com/apps matches your webapps url you're hosting it on

Comment: Is there a full example on how to get a c# client talking to SS to authenticate with Fb?